# Common_table_exprs with interlaced Lag() function not able to reference column in Select/update

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have wrote the following query to fix some wrongly logged data
which normaly records the timestamp (uniqueidentifier) in 10 min spaces

**You probably can skip query explaination and jump to Query / ERRO**

Some timestamps howeever are logged at timestamps with e.g.11 or 16 minutes
Sometimes there are even more entries between the 10 min. interval , eather with the correct 10 minute times or also several ones between the 10 min interval

**Example DB**

```
plantid                                 Value               Timestamp  
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    1.10000002384186    2013-10-26 06:01:00.000
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    1.21000000238418    2013-10-26 06:01:10.000

1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    1.10000002384186    2013-10-26 06:02:00.000
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    1.10000002384186    2013-10-26 06:05:00.000

1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    0.800000011920929   2013-10-26 08:50:00.000
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    0.800000011920929   2013-10-26 08:52:00.000
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    0.800000011920929   2013-10-26 08:56:00.000

1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    0.800000011920929   2013-10-26 10:20:00.000
1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13    0.800000011920929   2013-10-26 10:36:00.000
```

**Example DB explained**
Block 1 correct entry
Block 2 no 10 min Value update to 06:00 and delete other value
Block 3 Correct value 8:50 delete other two entries
Block 4 10:20 correct update 10:36 to 10:30

As you can see in the Table above the reason for the query is to delete/update timestamp values 
In the Second paragraph in example DB the update query stops because after updating first value, second value cannot updated to same timestamp
That why I added another where clause which is causing my Problem (explained after query)

**Query**

```
DECLARE @deviceId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13';
with T1 as(
Select 
plantid,
LAG([S2].timestamp) over (order by [S2].timestamp) previosTime,
[S2].timestamp,
Dateadd(minute,-DATEPART(MINUTE, [s2].[timestamp])%10,[s2].[timestamp]) as newtimestamp
from [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG] [S2]
where [S2].[PlantID] = @deviceId
and [s2].LogInterval = 10
), T2 as(
SELECT plantid,previosTime, [s].[Timestamp], newtimestamp
FROM T1 [s]
WHERE [s].[PlantID] = @deviceId
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 00
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 10
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 20
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 30
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 40
and DATEPART(MINUTE, Timestamp) <> 50
)--Select * from T2;
-- #### delete data where original timestamp is already present ####
--Delete [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG]
--from [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG] k
--right join T2 on t2.timestamp = k.Timestamp and t2.plantid = K.PlantID
--where k.plantid = '1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13' and t2.previosTime = t2.newtimestamp
-- ####test select for delete/update####
Select k.plantid, k.timestamp, t2.timestamp, t2.previosTime, t2.newtimestamp, 
LAG([K].timestamp) over (order by [K].timestamp) previosTimeNewSelect
from [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG] as k
right join T2 on t2.timestamp = k.Timestamp and t2.plantid = K.PlantID
where k.plantid = @deviceId and t2.previosTime <> t2.newtimestamp and  t2.newtimestamp <> previosTimeNewSelect
-- #### update the data ####
--update [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG] 
--SET timestamp = T2.newtimestamp
--FROM [LocationWN_MNC1VE].[dbo].[T_WTG] [f]
--right join T2 ON T2.timestamp = F.Timestamp and t2.plantid = f.PlantID
--where f.plantid = '1F617EDE-7B11-416A-B8D1-FDD566020E13' and t2.previosTime <> t2.newtimestamp
```

**ERROR**
While adding the where caluse  "and t2.newtimestamp <> previosTimeNewSelect"
to be able to identify doubled data sets, I get the following error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   Invalid column name 'previosTimeNewSelect'.

I have tried every Option  with k and T2

please let me know where my error is

Comment: it is in the last select statement previosTimeNewSelect  ctr +f, thanks for the spelling advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause is logically evaluated before the select clause so `previosTimeNewSelect` is not available to you there.

You need to calculate the value for `previosTimeNewSelect` in a derived table or another CTE and then filter on the column in the where clause in the outer query.

Here is a simplified version of what you try to do.

```
declare @T table(ID int identity);

select T.ID,
       lag(T.ID) over (order by T.ID) as LID
from @T as T
where LID = 1;
```

Result:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'LID'.
```

Use a derived table instead

```
select TT.ID,
       TT.LID
from (
     select T.ID,
            lag(T.ID) over (order by T.ID) as LID
     from @T as T
     ) as TT
where TT.LID = 1;
```

or a CTE

```
with TT as
(
    select T.ID,
          lag(T.ID) over (order by T.ID) as LID
    from @T as T
)
select TT.ID,
       TT.LID
from TT
where TT.LID = 1
```